# Issue with GetDlgItem

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to do the following:

```
CComboBox *pComboBox;
CString newString;  
int iNewSelection = -1;

pComboBox = (CComboBox*)(this->GetDlgItem(IDC_METHOD));

NewMethod = pComboBox->GetCurSel();

if(NewMethod != CB_ERR)
{
    pComboBox->GetLBText(NewMethod, newString);
}
```

In the above NewMethod is an integer.

It works fine (kind of). The issue is following:

When I debug through the above code, stop at the IF condition and put the mouse cursor on NewMethod, I get some random value, but then it does go through the IF condition and I can see correct value in newString.

My question is: why I do not see correct integer value in NewMethod?

Many thanks.

Best Regards

Chintan

Comment: NewMethod is defiend as an integer.

Comment: Are you debugging a release build or a debug build with optimizations turned on? You get these sort of effects when debugging optimized code.

Comment: I am debugging in debug build.

Comment: Strange. I would expect something like this to happen if you observe the value of `NewMethod` at the line, at which it is being set.

Comment: Can it be in hexadecimal format? If it shows you value in hexadecimal format maybe you thought that it is a random value.

Comment: It is not hexadecimal. It is just random signed integer.

Comment: Since no function calls occur for the entire lifetime of the variable, the compiler probably did dead store elimination, which means the value is never written to memory. Disable all optimizations to force the value to be written. (Or drop to assembly language view to see the value in a register.)

Comment: The above code is a part of a function. So when I make a change in the dropdown menu, it does go inside the function and execute the above code. Just that I cannot get exact value in `NewMethod`.

Comment: What happens if you replace NewMethod with a fresh int just for the scope of the call. Does the same thing happen?

Comment: yeah. In fact, it does not even show anything when I put my cursor on the variable. Is it possible that something is wrong with the settings?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're source code and binary are out of sync, ie. you're debugging a DLL/EXE that has been compiled with different version of the source code.

During debug activate the Debug->Windows->Modules window and check that the DLL/EXE you're debugging is the same as the one you've been compiling with your source code (check date/times, symbol files etc.).

Comment: I did the above test and it looks like they are in sync. My project setup is as follows: The main project is divided into two parts. One is GUI and other is processing of signals, which is a DLL. The code that I pasted is in GUI project. The problem is that it is kind of working, because, I can see the value in `newString` is `""` and after the `if` condition, it does get the current selection from the dropdown list. Only that it does not show me correct inetger in `NewMethod` :(

Comment: (Excuse what may seem like silly questions but...) Just to check, the Debugging settings for your project has something like $(TargetPath) specified for the 'Command' and not some other EXE? Also, it all compiles without any errors?

Comment: Yes, it is specified for the 'Command' and it compiles perfectly fine, without any warning(s).

Comment: Is NewMethod a global/member/local variable?

Comment: NewMethod is a member variable.

Comment: Have you tried changing it's name to see if that's a problem?

Comment: I did use a different name. In fact, I assigned a -ve value to it and still after that I see different value in it.